# links not active in show toggled Div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I have a menu div which shows/hides based on click with jQuery, but none of the links are active when you put them in .. ideas?

I only have one item in the list that is a hyperlink. Once I can get it to work, I'll add it to the rest of the items .. however that one link doesn't work.

jQuery

```
  $(".sign_in").click(function() {
      $("#sign_box").toggle();     
      return false;
  });
  $("body #main").click(function() {
      $("#sign_box").hide();
      return false;
  });
```

CSS

```
#sign_box
    {
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.296875) 0px 3px 3px;
    width:170px; 
    background-color:#FFF; 
    border: 5px solid #CCC; 
    padding:8px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    z-index: 100;
    line-height: 16px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-top-top-radius: 5px 5px;
    color: #555;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    }
    .sign_in
    {
    color: White;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:#53A1DC; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px 4px;
    border-top-top-radius: 4px 4px;
    border:solid 1px #5ea0c1;
    padding:6px;
    }
    a.sign_in span 
    {
        background-image: url("../images/toggle_down_light.png");
        background-position: 100% 50%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding-right: 18px;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div><a href="#" class="sign_in"><span>User Options</span></a></div>
<div id="sign_box">
<ul class="account-links">
    <li><a href="../raceday/events/list">All Events</a></li>
    <li>My Events</li>
    <li>My Profile</li>
    <li>All Clubs</li>
    <li>Change My Password</li>
    <li>My Dependants</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "none of the links are active when you put them in"? And right now you only have _one_ link, the rest is just text.

Comment: I realize the others aren't actually links - the one that is doesn't work so I didn't add the other ones...

Comment: the return false in your click events is not stopping the typical anchor behavior, also not need to define what you want "Active" that is unclear. I would suggest you remove all the un-needed CSS from the style sheet and the real HTML so we can get a clear look at what you are trying to do.

Comment: Seems the link is working fine (although it obviously doesn't exist on that site): http://jsfiddle.net/4CwKA/. Are you sure the URL "../raceday/events/list" works on _your_ site? Also notice that ".." means "one directory down", so if you run this on "foo.com/bar", this link refers you "foo.com/raceday/etc...".

Comment: Yes ... it's not that the link doesn't go the desired source - when I'm looking at it .. and I click on the link, it doesn't even do anything in the browser .. like it's disabled..

Comment: could it have anything to do with "return false;" for when the box is being hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Only one of the items ***is*** a link, the "All Events" entry.  Add the anchor tag to the rest or associate a click event navigation via js to have them actually do something...

If you do have js code already wired up that makes the li items menus that go somewhere you should show us that code also...

Comment: I realize the others aren't actually links - the one that is doesn't work so I didn't add the other ones...